# Why looping through the array backwards is not returning reversed array of strings until I assigned it to the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I was doing this coding problem and where you have yo return reversed array of strings.

```
/**
 * @param {character[]} s
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
 */
var reverseString = function (s) {

};
```

where s is an array of string.

**Example**
Input: s = ["h","e","l","l","o"]
Output: ["o","l","l","e","h"]

*I have done this*

```
/**
 * @param {character[]} s
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
 */
var reverseString = function (s) {
      let arr = [];

     for (let i = s.length-1;i >= 0; i--){
         arr.push(s[i]);
     }
     return arr;
};
```

But this is the wrong solution. IDKW?

After I did this:

```
/**
 * @param {character[]} s
 * @return {void} Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
 */
var reverseString = function (s) {
    let reversed = [];

    for (let i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed.push(s[i]);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        s[i] = reversed[i];
    }

    return reversed;
};
```

It runs perfectly can you explain why the upper one is not executing correctly, why it is pushing the elements in the array as the original one instead of putting in reversing order.

Comment: Original one should work correctly - it just doesn't meet the requirement, which is to update the param `s`.

Comment: Is there something unclear about **Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.**?  The exercise does not want your function to return a new array, it wants the array that was passed in to be modified.

Comment: `@return {void} Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.`

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are creating a new array (`arr = []`) and push the original elements onto it (`arr.push(s[i])`), whereas the requirements is to modify the original array itself ("*modify s in-place*").

Do note that your second example is a bit incorrect: It modifies the original array (`s[i] = reversed[i]`) yet it returns the new array (`return reversed`) whereas the function is supposed to return nothing (`@return {void}`).

```js
var reverseString = function (s) {
    // This creates a new array
    let reversed = [];

    for (let i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // This pushes the original elements onto the new array, backwards
        reversed.push(s[i]);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        // This modifies the original array
        s[i] = reversed[i];
    }

    // And yet you return the new array
    return reversed;
};
```

Array has a built-in method to reverse itself: [`Array#reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse). It does exactly what you want: reverse the array *in-place*.

```js
function reverseArrayOfStrings(s) {
  s.reverse();
};
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function reverseArrayOfStrings(s) {
  s.reverse();
};

const testcase = ['1', '2', '3'];
console.log(testcase);

reverseArrayOfStrings(testcase);
console.log(testcase);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to write your own, read on.

First, we make a middle point and call it `pivot`: `pivot = Math.floor(s.length / 2)`. It serves as the stop for our loop. Then, we swap the elements, pair by pair:

```
Original:
┌───────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ Indices:  │  0  │  1  │  2  │  3  │  4  │
├───────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ Elements: │ '1' │ '2' │ '3' │ '4' │ '5' │
└───────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

Swap the element at index 0 with the one at 4:
┌───────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ Indices:  │  0  │  1  │  2  │  3  │  4  │
├───────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ Elements: │ '5' │ '2' │ '3' │ '4' │ '1' │
└───────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

Swap the element at index 1 with the one at 3:
┌───────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ Indices:  │  0  │  1  │  2  │  3  │  4  │
├───────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ Elements: │ '5' │ '4' │ '3' │ '2' │ '1' │
└───────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘

Swap the element at index 2 with itself (i.e. no change):
┌───────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ Indices:  │  0  │  1  │  2  │  3  │  4  │
├───────────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ Elements: │ '5' │ '4' │ '3' │ '2' │ '1' │
└───────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Let's call the indices to swap in one turn `x` and `y` (`x <= y`). `x` starts at 0, whereas `y` starts at `s.length - 1` (`5 - 4`). `x` increases by 1 each turn, whereas `y` decreases by 1 in the same turn. This leads to a formula:

```
y = s.length - x - 1
```

To make things easy, we loop from 0 to `pivot`, inclusively. This makes `x` the same as `index`:

```js
for (let index = 0, pivot = Math.floor(s.length / 2); index < pivot; index++) {
    // This syntax is called "destructuring".
    // It assigns the current value of s[s.length - index - 1] to s[index]
    // and vice versa concurrently, effectively swapping their places.

    [s[index], s[s.length - index - 1]] = [s[s.length - index - 1], s[index]];
    // To compare: [s[x], s[y]] = [s[y], s[x]];
}
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function reverseArrayOfStrings(s) {
  for (let index = 0, pivot = Math.floor(s.length / 2); index < pivot; index++) {
      // This syntax is called "destructuring"
      // It assigns the current value of s[s.length - index - 1] to s[index]
      // and vice versa concurrently, effectively swapping their places.
      [s[index], s[s.length - index - 1]] = [s[s.length - index - 1], s[index]];
  }
};

const testcases = [
  ['1', '2', '3'],
  ['1', '2', '3', '4']
];
testcases.forEach(testcase => {
  console.log('Original:', testcase);
  reverseArrayOfStrings(testcase);
  console.log('Modified:', testcase);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

As a side note, a recent change to JS adds a method for creating a reversed array without modifying the original: [`Array#toReversed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toReversed).

Comment: It seems likely that the goal of the problem was to implement their own version of `reverse()` and not just call that method within their own.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added a verbose explanation in case OP needs it.